# Why does the comments score distribution show a logarithmic trend?

Tags: discussion, comments, data-explorer

I was looking at [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution) [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/2361) (SEDE) query on the comments score distribution.

I've noticed that, for nearly all users I've checked, that the trend is (somewhat) logarithmic with the number of votes. Curious enough.

Is there any mathematical explanation behind this phenomenon?

Comment: It might be a bit broad, but you could consider asking this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.  My basic guess is just that the sample size of comments is large enough to see trends, and that the lack of comment downvotes plays a role in the distribution.

Comment: I don't know about *"mathematical"*, but logically that's what I'd expect - the larger the number of upvotes, the less likely it is to happen for a given comment.

Comment: You would expect any given comment or answer's score to increase exponentially with time, a natural growth law.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To look at this more globally, consider the frequency distribution of all comment scores in the history of the site ([SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/370202/global-comment-score-distribution)). In the plot below, comment scores are represented by points, proportion of comments with that score is on the y-axis, and the rank of that score's frequency is on the x-axis (score 0 is rank 1, score 1 is rank 2, and so on). Note that both the x and y axes are log transformed.

[image]

Visually there appears to be a linear relationship between the log of the proportion of comments with a given score and the log of the rank of the comment score's frequency; a linear regression model fit to this data would achieve R^2 value 0.998. This suggests that [Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law) (a discrete form of the power law) might be appropriate to model the frequency of different comment scores, though note that [more sophisticated tests](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/070710111) are often used when testing for power laws. [Power laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) have the property of scale invariance; in this case doubling the rank of a comment score (roughly equivalent to doubling the comment score) leads to roughly an 86% reduction in the comment count regardless of the current score.

[However, care needs to be taken to conclude that a distribution fits a power law](http://martinhilbert.net/Powerlaw_ProgressDiffusion_Hilbert.pdf); one important component of this would be putting forth a credible explanation for why the data might be expected to follow a power law. I think in this case [preferential attachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_attachment) (the concept that "the rich get richer," meaning highly upvoted comments are more likely to receive further upvotes) might be a reasonable explanation for why we might expect comment scores to follow a power law. Highly voted comments probably have particularly interesting material, which would increase the probability that they would be further upvoted by a visitor. Additionally, since Stack Overflow highlights highly voted comments by displaying them even when there are many other comments on a post and by changing their color to draw attention, the website itself also encourages further voting on highly upvoted comments.